# What am I trying to calculate? Probability/Odds/Accuracy?

Tags: statistics

I am a bit lost on what exactly I am trying to calculate here. I record events that happen randomly in regards to trading. For instance, when a coin (crypto) rises 10%, I have a script that records a timestamp of when it happens and the highest  number that it hit.

The over all goal of what I'm trying to achieve is code a tool from the timestamps that will give you an estimated time of when the next event is going to happen, as well as the chance of it actually being accurate.

For instance, we'll say Bitcoin to keep things simple. (This is just an example and not real values) Bitcoin has had random rises of 10% over a 3 month period. If I average the difference between timestamps and the average time between each event is 3 days, then is it safe to assume that I can code the tool to say the next event should happen 3 days from the last event?

What am I trying to calculate in terms of accuracy? For instance, the predicted rise in 3 days doesn't happen. What do I convey in a calculation that says: Expected 10% bitcoin rise in 3 days; 42% accuracy (based on it actually happening vs not happening)

Really appreciate any help on this. I never took statistics, but this sounds like probability to me. I'm just not sure what line of thinking I need to heads toward so I can translate it into code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say this is a really difficult problem since what you want is the distribution of the time to event. We don't know this distribution. There are a few ways you can go on.

You could make some modelling assumptions. For example, you could assume the time to event is random, a.k.a., exponentially distributed. The parameter for the exponential distribution, you could estimate using maximum likelihood, for example. There are some tests available whether the exponential distribution is a good fit (google goodness-of-fit tests) such as the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test. So you should use those to check this assumption. Finally, you can calculate $1-F(3)$ where $F$ is the corresponding distribution function of your particular distribution. This is something you can either calculate theoretically of estimate fairly easy.

Or you could try to estimate it using nonparametric statistics. For example, kernel density estimation. This works as follows. You observed t_i, i = 1, ..., n times to event. Then, given a parameter h (which you can choose freely, although there are some basic rules) and a kernel K (for example a Gaussian distribution), you can estimate the density according to
$$ f(x) \approx \frac{1}{N h} \sum_{i=1}^{N} K((x-t_i)/h)$$
Then, what you want is to estimate
$$ \int_{3}^{\infty} f(x)\,\mathrm{d} x $$
if you want to know the probability of the event not happening in three days. This you can calculate using the integrate function in R for example or you could use some other tool, for example simulation works pretty good here.

I am not saying this will work in practice since working with financial time series is not super trivial but the above methods will at least provide better results than you are using right now.

Comment: I will definitely take a look into this. Thank you for your time.